# How to fetch Rows have not this column value in another table column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

`Tb_Product_Options`:

```
Product_Id     Option_Id
    1              5
    1              7
    2              3
    3              9
    3              6
```

Now I want to get all `Product_Id`s have not this values : `'5,9'`.
at this example my result must be: `2` (`product_id`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can aggregation :

```
select Product_Id
from table t
group by Product_Id
having sum ( Option_Id in (5,9) ) = 0;
```

If you want all columns then you can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.Product_Id = t.Product_Id and t1.Option_Id in (5,9)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, we would use an exclusion join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
           FROM my_table x
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y
             ON y.stuff = x.stuff
            AND y.other_stuff IN(some,values)
          WHERE y.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This surely works:

```
    select product_id

    from Tb_Product_Options

    where product_id not in (
                                select product_id

                                from Tb_Product_Options 

                                where option_id in (5,9)
                                          )
```